# How to pass parameters after variable call and get output to a file

Tags: bash, shell

Currently I have the below but I want to be able to pass variables to the `file_in` and still have the `file_out`

Current:

```
function Runsshlocal
{
  HOSTS=$1
  SID=$2
  file_in=$3
 file_out=$4

 ssh -q ${HOSTS} "ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=${SID}; . oraenv -s;sqlplus -s \"/ as sysdba \" " < ${file_in} > ${file_out}
}
```

How can I pass variables/parameters after the `file_in` as variables?

Trying to do this:

```
function Runsshlocal
{
  HOSTS=$1
  SID=$2
  file_in=$3
  file_out=$4

  ssh -q ${HOSTS} "ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=${SID}; . oraenv -s;sqlplus -s \"/ as sysdba \" " <  ${file_in} ${param1} ${param2} > ${file_out}
}
```

I tried this but did not work.

```
function Runsshlocal
{
  HOSTS=$1
  SID=$2
  file_in=$3
  file_out=$4
  shift 4
  SQL_PARAMS=$@


  ssh -q ${HOSTS} "ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=${SID}; . oraenv -s;sqlplus -s \"/ as sysdba \" " <   ${file_in} ${param1} ${param2} > ${file_out}
}
```

Comment: Code which doesn’t do what you want is a terrible way to explain what it actually is that you want.

Comment: BTW, `function funcname {` is syntax from legacy 80s ksh that bash supports for backwards compatibility (without supporting some of the more obscure meanings the construct had in ksh, where it changed whether `typeset` was creating local or global variables); the early-90s publication of POSIX.2 standardized `funcname() {` with no preceding `function`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, using *heredoc*:

```
#!/bin/bash

Runsshlocal() {
    host=$1
    sid=$2
    file_in=$3
    file_out=$4

    ssh -q "$host"<<EOF
    ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID="$sid"
    . oraenv -s
    sqlplus -s \"/ as sysdba \" " <  "$file_in" "$param1" "$param2" > "$file_out"
EOF
}
```

---

> `cat <<EOF` followed by several lines of text, followed by the literal string `EOF` on a new line, NOT indented. The portion between the `EOF`s is passed to the command as standard input. If `'EOF'` is 'quoted', substitutions WON'T be done; otherwise they are. See `<<-` for the indented variety (not recommended, need TABs).

Comment: I would like to do it within a function.

Comment: Then put it in a function.

Comment: Do you need help to use a function? Anyway, added function