# Bash Pass local file with params to remote server

Tags: bash, ksh

How can I run a file and pass variables to a file that is local over to a remote server?

When I run the code below, with redirecting the `file_in` without the `<`, it does work.

This works, but the file has to be on the remote server: `./remoteserver/xxxxx.sql`

```
function Runsshlocal
{
  HOSTS=$1
  SID=$2
  file_in=$3
  shift 3
  SQL_PARAMS=$@
  output=$(
    echo "exit" | 
      ssh -q ${HOSTS} "ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=${SID}; . oraenv -s;
        sqlplus -s \"/ as sysdba \"  @${file_in} ${SQL_PARAMS}" 
  )
  echo $output 
}

TEST=$(Runsshlocal ${TARGET_SERVER} ${TARGET_SID} /remoteserver/xxxxx.sql  ${PARAM1} ${PARAM2})
echo $TEST
```

*But* I would like to run it where the `xxxxx.sql` file is on the local server and not the remote server.

This does not work:

```
function Runsshlocal
{
  HOSTS=$1
  SID=$2
  file_in=$3
  shift 3
  SQL_PARAMS=$@
  output=$(
    echo exit | ssh -q ${HOSTS} "ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=${SID}; . oraenv -s;sqlplus -s \"/ as   sysdba \" " <  @${file_in} ${SQL_PARAMS} 
  )
  echo $output }

  TEST=$(
    Runsshlocal ${TARGET_SERVER} ${TARGET_SID} /localserver/xxxxx.sql  ${PARAM1} ${PARAM2}
  )
  echo $TEST
```

Comment: Is this different from your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77996179/how-to-pass-parameters-after-variable-call-and-get-output-to-a-file

Comment: Can you use `scp` to copy the file to the remote system? If not, you can redirect the ssh input to the file `ssh ... < "$file_in"`

Comment: @Barmar , I cannt scp the file. 
can you give an example of inputting the file + variables into a file first?

Comment: @Shaz, ...if you want a tested answer, can you build a [mre] that can be run by people who don't run Oracle?

Comment: Why is this tagged with both [tag:bash] and [tag:ksh]?

Comment: `SQL_PARAMS=$@` is _extremely_ lossy, since it's compressing an array into a string, losing data around what the original boundaries were. If you want to avoid throwing away data it needs to be `sql_params=( "$@" )`

Comment: BTW, in ` < @${file_in}` you can't use the `@`. When an `@` is passed on the sqlplus command line it's interpreted _by sqlplus_, but `<` is interpreted _by the shell itself_, which doesn't need or understand the `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Barmar's answer, try a heredoc with an embedded herestring:

```bash
output=$(ssh -q ${HOSTS} << _REMOTE_COMMANDS_
ORAENV_ASK=NO
ORACLE_SID=${SID}
. oraenv -s
# edit: using single quotes to surround SQL is probably a bad idea...
#                                                      v                 v
sqlplus /dev/stdin -s '/ as sysdba ' ${SQL_PARAMS} <<< "$(cat "$file_in")"
_REMOTE_COMMANDS_
)
```

Depending on the contents of the sql code, maybe embed a heredoc in the heredoc.

```bash
output=$(ssh -q ${HOSTS} << _REMOTE_COMMANDS_
ORAENV_ASK=NO
ORACLE_SID=${SID}
. oraenv -s
sqlplus /dev/stdin -s '/ as sysdba ' ${SQL_PARAMS} << '_END_SQL_'
$(cat "$file_in")
_END_SQL_
_REMOTE_COMMANDS_
)
```

Comment: Probably should have a `printf -v SQL_PARAMS '%q ' "$@"` or equivalent to actually _generate_ the SQL_PARAMS variable in a way that's less horrible/lossy than the existing `SQL_PARAMS=$@`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
output=$(ssh -q ${HOSTS} "ORAENV_ASK=NO;ORACLE_SID=${SID}; . oraenv -s;sqlplus /dev/stdin -s \"/ as   sysdba \" " ${SQL_PARAMS} < "$file_in" )
```

This uses the SQL file as standard input to `ssh`. `sqlplus` will then read it as its own input.

Comment: Just tried that but didnt work.

Comment: @Shaz, ...it works perfectly well in general. If there's something special/different about your environment that requires a different solution, you need to give us a [mre] that lets us see that problem ourselves.

Comment: @Shaz, mind, you can use `echo exit |` or `<"$file_in"`, but _not both at once_; each process can get stdin from only one place -- file descriptor 0 can point to a file _or_ it can point to pipe from an `echo` command; but it can't be coming from two different places at the same time. That's true even if you use `<"$file_in"` outside the ssh command and `echo exit |` inside it -- if you try to do that instead of following this answer faithfully, the `echo exit |` will replace stdin of sqlplus so it no longer points to ssh's original stdin with the contents of the input file.

Comment: @Shaz, ...if you want the file _followed by_ `exit`, then maybe you need something like `ssh ... < <(cat -- "$file_in" - <<<"exit")` -- but that's pure speculation since the question doesn't currently give us enough information to know what you're doing that fails.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was going to suggest that, but I wasn't sure you can mix `exit` with SQL. I assumed sqlplus will just exit when it reads EOF, so it's not needed.

Comment: @Barmar, ...it's been a lot of years since I was at an Oracle shop, so the details have long since fled my memory -- but sqlplus was an astonishingly ill-behaved piece of software, to the point that I wrote my own SQL client to use when scripting. Anyhow, intent behind my comment was to handle the case where OP may still be trying to use their `echo "exit" |` (incorrectly assuming that your removal of it was oversight vs intent), which would explain the redirection in your answer not working for them.

Comment: more so it wasnt the exit but passing in a local file remotely with parameters given. 

I can pass just the file itself and get the output but when I ass parameters, it fails.

Comment: @Shaz, one notable thing is that right now you aren't `export`ing your parameters. You want to use `set -a` to turn on auto-export, as in `set -a; foo=bar; baz=qux` if you want `foo` and `baz` to be exported to subprocesses. And on a separate note, if you want to log the actual command line used to get a more concrete read on where/how things are being lost or misinterpreted, that's what `set -x` is for.